# Table view is showing empty cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel

I have 2 sections, First have 1 row and Second have 4 rows. I can see the switch, labels and text fields in the storyboard. It is loading blank in the Simulator. I have checked all the IBOutlets are connected.

Following is my code from Table View Controller

```
import UIKit

class InfoTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var sectionArray: NSMutableArray = ["Social Security Benefits", "Demographics"]
var socialArray: NSMutableArray = ["Estimate Social Security Benefits"]
var demoArray: NSMutableArray = ["Name:", "DOB:", "Age of Retirement:", "Years of Retirement"]
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return self.sectionArray.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0{
        return socialArray.count
    } else {
        return demoArray.count
    }
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            println(indexPath.section)
            println(indexPath.row)
            let cell: SocialTableCell = SocialTableCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "social")
            cell.social?.text = "Estimate"
            cell.toggle?.setOn(false, animated: true)

            return cell
        }
    } else if indexPath.section == 1 {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            println(indexPath.section)
            println(indexPath.row)
            let cell: NameTableCell = NameTableCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "name")
            return cell
        }else if indexPath.row == 1{
            println(indexPath.section)
            println(indexPath.row)
            let cell: DOBTableCell = DOBTableCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "DOB")
        }else if indexPath.row == 2{
            println(indexPath.section)
            println(indexPath.row)
            let cell: RetirementTableCell = RetirementTableCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "AgeOfRetirement")
        }else if indexPath.row == 3{
            println(indexPath.section)
            println(indexPath.row)
            let cell: YearsRetirementTableCell = YearsRetirementTableCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "YearsOfRetirement")
        }

    }


    return UITableViewCell()


    //cell.configureFlatCellWithColor(UIColor.greenSeaColor(), selectedColor: UIColor.cloudsColor(), roundingCorners: UIRectCorner())


}
}
```

I also have created 5 Table View Cells Classes for each cell. I also have checked for all the identifiers and they are correct.

Following is the image of my storyboard

[image]

But when i run it, the simulator only shows sections and the cells are empty.

[image]

Any Help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: did you set the delegate and datasource?

Comment: I used tableviewcontroller not view controller with tableview, It is set automatically!

Comment: You need to read the "Table View Programming Guide" and learn how to properly implement your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. You are not properly dequeueing your cells and you make no attempt to put data into your cells. That's why they are blank.

Comment: I do know that I am not setting the the lower cells but I was setting the social cell and it wasn't working. I didn't wanted to waste my time setting those when first one is not working.

Comment: Make sure that `cell.social` and `cell.toggle` aren't `nil`.

Comment: They aren't, I can see them in storyboard and I am setting them to values in the method above.

Comment: But at runtime, in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, have you verified that they aren't `nil`? Use the debugger and see.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with using Static cells.

1. Go to your Table view => Attribute Inspector => in content select static cells, then in section , put 2 ( because you have 2 sections )

[image]

2. Then Click a one section in Storyboad Hierarchy => Attribute Inspector => put number of rows ( put 1 because you have one row in 1st section ) you want in each section.Again select the other section and put number of rows you want( put 4 becuase you have 4 rows in 2nd section)

[image]

3. Then Click the each row cell and add Label and put your label name. and you can put toggle button too for tour first section.
4. Create a new cocoa touch class :- The class look like this ( You Should comment or deleter these functions ,

   ```
       // MARK: - Table view data source

    /*
        override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
         // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of sections.
           return 1
         }        

         override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
         // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
           return 2
         }
      */

     /*
         override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
          let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

          // Configure the cell...

            return cell
         }
    */
   ```

And Finally Table class looks like this ,

```
     import UIKit

       class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

         override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()

           // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
          // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

          // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.

           }  

           override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
             super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
             // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
           }

           override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
           super.viewWillAppear(animated)

           }
       }
```

Comment: If I do it this way, I won't be able to change the looks of the cell like round edges or different color sections. I haven't looked at it yet but how would I look at using the numbers from the input to compute my answers for different tab.

Comment: You can add a image or label to use different colour sections, Try this out !!

Answer (score 0):

This is how your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` should look like. Below is an example from your first section first row, you can align all others accordingly.

As a side note, noticed that except for your first section first row, for all other table rows you are not setting any labels etc. and that control end up coming to statement `return UITableViewCell()` leading to empty cells. Please double check that too.

```
if indexPath.row == 0 {
    println(indexPath.section)
    println(indexPath.row)

    let socialCellId: NSString = "social"
    var cell: SocialTableCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(socialCellId) as SocialTableCell

    if cell == nil
    {
        cell = SocialTableCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier:socialCellId)
    }

    cell.social?.text = "Estimate"
    cell.toggle?.setOn(false, animated: true)

    return cell
}
```

Comment: I tried the solution, 2 things. cell can not be compared to nil because cell is of type secTableViewCell not secTableViewCell? (Optional<secTableViewCell>). Because it's not an optional, it cannot be nil.  2nd I can't call social and toggle because they are part of SocialTableCell(I created) and according to you solution cell is of UITableViewCell.

Comment: For your first point, here we are trying to get a `SocialTableCell` from the pool of already existing cells which may return `nil` for instance in your initial rendering. You may put a break point and check. And for the second  one, it was a typo from my side, corrected it now :). @Dereck

Comment: I tried the first point again and did the break point and checked but Xcode is keep on giving me error "binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'uitableviewcell' and 'nil'"

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue, and none of the comments above helped me. I finally figured it out, perhaps you were having the same issue.

For me, I had accidentally copied and pasted a second tableview in the designer. The second tableView was on top of the first but only the first table view was connected to my TableViewController, and so the cells for the visible one at runtime were never created, hence blank.

Check that, hopefully that helps.

[Double TableView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6rDI.png)